# How to hide exe dll in C++?

Tags: c++, dll

I have my program (.exe) and it depends on 3 DLLs to work, but, I want to hide these DLLs, is there any way for me to "put them in .exe" these dlls? Only have the .exe,is there any method to do this?

Info:
Program's ling: C++
DLLs: {libcrypto-1_1-x64, libcurl-x64, libssl-1_1-x64}

Comment: You could use the `.lib` versions of the libraries instead of the `.DLL`s.

Comment: I think, dont have .lib of this dlls

Comment: If you can't find precompiled static versions, you could compile them yourself.

Comment: how i can do that? do uk???

Comment: Download the source code and read the build instructions. For `libcurl` there's a `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` option that is `ON` by default. Turning that `OFF` will make it build static libraries. OpenSSL probably has something similar.

Comment: You may just want to create an installer for your application.

Comment: My app insnt a program to install, is a executable file

Comment: Maybe you can make a small application (as in number of code lines) that has the executable you want to run + all the dlls in a binary resource and it extracts these from to the temporary folder and then runs your main application. That way you can create a normal application that statically links to the import libraries but is only one executable to download and nothing to install.

Comment: Yess @drescherjm, I did it and it worked just as well as I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the static versions of the libraries, their code will be compiled directly into your EXE, and then you won't need DLLs at all.

But, if you need to use DLLs, then you can compile them into your EXE's resources, and then extract them at runtime to temp files before using them.  You won't be able to *statically* link to any of the DLL functions at compile-time, or else your app won't run at all.  But you can *dynamically* load them at runtime using `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` (or, if you compiler supports it, use [delay-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls)), which will allow you to extract the DLLs before calling their functions.

Comment: Like "inject" the dll in my own program's process?

Comment: in this case, is like "extract" the dlls, and load in my program?

Comment: Like, writing an [`.rc` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files) that references the DLLs as content for `RCDATA` resources, and then using your compiler toolchain's **resource compiler** to compile that `.rc` into a `.res` file that you can then *link* into your `.exe` file. At runtime, you can then use the `(Find|Load|Lock)Resource()` functions to access the data of the DLL files, and write them out to temp files using `CreateFile()` and `WriteFile()`. And then load those files with `LoadLibrary()`.